# How can I know when does the managed object context finished saving?

Tags: ios, core-data

When I'm saving a huge amount of data and immediately existing the app, the Managed Object Context didn't finnish to save and the data is lost.

Is there a way to get notified when the save has finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register your object with the NSNotificationCenter to receive the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification with the `NSManagedObjectContext` in question.